# Vulkan Validation Layers not showing up on Android Samsung S22

Tags: android, vulkan

I am having a hard time enabling validation layers on my Samsung S22. Has anyone done successfully with any Android device Vulkan capable? Here's what I have tried on my Galaxy S22:

This is an Android test code just to print them:

```
void testValidationLayers() {

    // Enable just the Khronos validation layer.
    static const char *layers[] = {"VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation"};

    // Get the layer count using a null pointer as the last parameter.
    uint32_t instance_layer_present_count = 0;
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&instance_layer_present_count, nullptr);

    // Enumerate layers with a valid pointer in the last parameter.
    VkLayerProperties *layer_props = new VkLayerProperties[instance_layer_present_count];
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&instance_layer_present_count, layer_props);

    // Show all layers
    for (uint32_t ii = 0; ii < instance_layer_present_count; ii++) {
        VkLayerProperties *lp = &layer_props[ii];
        char *pName = lp->layerName;
        if (pName != nullptr) {
            LOGD("%s", pName);
        }
    }

    delete[] layer_props;
    LOGD("%s", "done");
}
```

Yet, when I this code on a PC with an AMD and NVidia card attached, I get a bunch of layers, see below:

[image]

But virtually the same code produces nothing on Android. The enumeration comes out with 0 always. See below:

[image]

Do I have to do anything else to get the debug layer to show up? If you have it working, mind share which device you use?

thank you.

Comment: are you sure that android includes it?

Comment: that is my question really. Has anyone be able to get the validation layers to work? It may not be available on Android. I just don't know.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/graphics/validation-layer

Comment: The validation layers do work and are tested on Android. If the Android developer documentation isn't good enough I'd recommend going to the Vulkan discord. They have a channel specifically for Android users that would be able to help you.

Comment: @jpr42 have you tried and got it working successfully? I followed the exact link you posted and wrote based on that sample. It enumerates always 0 validation layers in two Android devices (both Samsung However). What device have you tried that worked? thx

Answer (score 0):

They work, but it is really complicated to setup. The best is to download this project to see the whole setup. Not simple at all :(

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vulkan-tutorials/tree/master/tutorial02_prebuild_layers